# Difficulty in database table normalization (2NF)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

The following table design (see below for the full schema) leaves a lot to be desired and has caused many difficulties, but I can't figure out how best to normalize them. The purposes of the tables are:

1. `ICD9` — to provide a master look-up of `CICD9` and `CDESC` combinations. Each combination is to be unique in the `ICD9` table&hellip no duplicates.
2. Changes to the unique key (`CICD9,CDESC`) in the `ICD9` table are to be cascaded to the `DX` table. The `DX` table is never to have a (`CICD9,CDESC`) combination that is not represented in the `ICD9` table.
3. Table `DX` -- The records in this table give specific information about the person on a specific time. The records in this table can not be duplicated based on a Key(`CICD9,CDESC,GROUPID,TPOSTED`) where the `GROUPID` is unique to the person and the `TPOSTED` is the time the record was created.
4. As can be seen below, the `DX` table contains associated non-key information on the records with the unique key(`CICD9,CDESC,GROUPID,TPOSTED`).

Sometimes duplicate records are created in `ICD9` and `DX` due to bad data. For instance:

```
ICD9
|CICD9|CDESC    |
|1234 |"  TEST1"|
|1234 |"TEST1"  |

DX
|CICD9|CDESC   |GROUPID|TPOSTED |
|1234 |"  TEST1|H      |12301212|
|1234 |"TEST1" |H      |12301212|
```

In order to resolve the duplicate data, the `ICD9` table is updated, modifying `CDESC` so that `"  TEST1"` becomes `"TEST1"`. Because this is part of the Key(`CICD9,CDESC`), the cascade set on the foreign key in `DX` will cause the `CDESC` column in `DX` to also change. This change may cause the records in the `DX` table to conflict with other records in the `DX` table and violate the no duplicate allowed on the Key(`CICD9,CDESC,GROUPID,TPOSTED`) in the `DX` table.

It's OK for me to delete the duplicate record in `ICD9`, and I have gotten that working. But I need to preserve the rest of the data in `DX` (like `RESOLVED`, and `TREATED`), so I can't just delete one of the rows. I also need to keep the unique Key(`CICD9,CDESC,GROUPID,TPOSTED`). It has been suggested that this needs to be normalized, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
      CREATE TABLE icd9
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  cicd9 character varying(8),
  cdesc character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  chronic boolean,
  common boolean,
  CONSTRAINT pk_icd9_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid),
  CONSTRAINT constraint_cdesc UNIQUE (cicd9, cdesc),
  CONSTRAINT desccheck CHECK (cdesc::text <> ''::text)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


     CREATE TABLE dx
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  cpatient character varying(33) NOT NULL,
  cicd9 character varying(8),
  cdesc character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  tposted timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  resolved boolean DEFAULT false,
  treated boolean DEFAULT false,
  chronic boolean DEFAULT false,
  groupid character varying(33) NOT NULL,
  service integer DEFAULT 0,
  explanation text,
  pmh boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT pk_dx_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid),
  CONSTRAINT dx_cpatient_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cpatient)
      REFERENCES patients (cpatient) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT dx_groupid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
      REFERENCES charts (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_icd9 FOREIGN KEY (cicd9, cdesc)
      REFERENCES icd9 (cicd9, cdesc) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT noduplicate_dx UNIQUE (cicd9, cdesc, groupid, tposted),
  CONSTRAINT desccheck CHECK (cdesc::text <> ''::text),
  CONSTRAINT groupcheck CHECK (groupid::bpchar <> ''::bpchar),
  CONSTRAINT patientcheck CHECK (cpatient::bpchar <> ''::bpchar)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: @joDouglass Yes. The constraint in icd9 does fire when a duplicate record is created in ICD9 table--which I am using a stored procedure to detect and remove before failure. However, the "bad data" is usually only that of misspellings or insufficient description--not actually "wrong" in the meaning, just poorly written. So deleting child records in Dx is not an acceptable solution, and any changes in the ICD9 table will need to have their Dx children moved to the "better" ICD9 record. Essentially, I need to avoid losing data in Dx, correcting it, yes, losing it, no. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80441/discussion-between-jo-douglass-and-alan-wayne).

Comment: BTW: what are all these timestamps doing in the icd9 table? Do you intend to allow for multiple versions/revisions of the codebook to coexist?

Comment: @wildplasser The original records were to have a "creation" timestamp, and a timestamp for when (or if) anything was changed. This was used when backing up the records to another machine. The tposted timestamp was specific and is never changed as it is not part of the "container", but of the "data". Is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simplifying the updates and deletions

First off, since you're using surrogate primary keys, your foreign keys should point to those, not to the unique keys that your surrogate keys are standing in for. One of the benefits of using surrogate keys is precisely that it makes life a lot easier when you have a unique key where one or more of the columns is likely to change; you won't need to cascade updates anymore, because the fields are only held in one place. You already have suitable unique constraints to manage the data quality.

Remove the `cicd9` and `cdesc` columns from `dx`. Add a column called something like `idc9_recid`. Change the unique constraint in `dx` to take account of this change. Ideally, you should make this change elsewhere in your database, as well.

You should be able to remove some of the over-engineering you've added in, then. I would generally take heavy usage of triggers as you've been describing as a bit of a warning sign that something is wrong. Make these changes, and then think about what's really necessary. All you should need to do is something like this:

```
update dx
set idc9_recid = 25
where idc9_recid = 12;

delete idc9
where recid = 12;
```

Obviously, you'll need to determine which rows you're interested in in order to determine those IDs - so you might in reality have either a query first to get the ID, or a sub-query which selects the correct ID. But regardless, it's much, much simpler than multiple triggers, counting on constraints to fail to set up updates, etc. Both from a development point of view, and from a support point of view later down the line.

#### Getting around the unique constraint error

In regards to the bad data/duplicate issue: In brief, the issue is that due to poor data quality, you sometimes end up with two `icd9` records which should actually be the same record. These can both have child records in `dx`, and while you need the unique constraint in `dx` to remain the same, you also need to preserve the data in the other fields in `dx`. The answer is to split `dx` into two tables, and move all of the fields which are not dependent on the unique key in `dx` into the new table, and then include a foreign key from the new table back to `dx`.

#### Example model

With a word of warning that this is **not necessarily the right design**, here's a simple model to help you visualize both of the above recommendations:

[image: Example data model for Alan Wayne]

(I used [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) to make the model - highly recommend if you haven't got any other modelling software, as you can use it to work through your changes before you actually apply them to the database. And it'll be helpful if you need to come back and ask more questions here.)

---

#### Where to go from here

I suspect the reason someone mentioned normalization to you is that it's clear that this database has been created without the process of normalization being followed. **Don't just implement what I've given you above.** It might help you fix this one issue, but I suspect that even in this small sample of your database there are other problems, and inevitably there will be further issues elsewhere.

For a starter - is your unique key in `dx` definitely right? Can you really not have two records in there for the same idc9, same group, and same time posted? Even if it's for a different record in `patients`? Or maybe there shouldn't be a foreign key to `patients` in that table? *(Note, these are just examples, things to get you thinking - no need to answer here.)*

And you definitely need to think about which key all of the fields that have been moved to `dx_detail` depend upon. It's probably the case that some belong in `dx` and some belong in `dx_detail` - but I can't tell you which because I do not know the meaning of the data.

So: the most important thing is that you **learn about data modelling and normalization** - [there](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) [are](http://www.slideshare.net/jagaarj/database-design-normalization) [lots](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) [of](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/) [resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fg7r3DgS3rA) [online](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) (that's 7 links, right there!). Or if you can explain to your employer that you really need some training before you pick up something as big as this - there's no shame in it, data modelling is its own discipline. I did a week-long professional course on data modelling which explained the process of creating a conceptual data model, then moving on to a logical data model and applying the rules of normalization to reach Boyce-Codd normal form. It was invaluable.

In short though, you need to think about what your data represents, and you need to think about what is actually dependent on what. Doing this via the process of normalization step-by-step helps you avoid missing anything, especially when you're new to the process.

I would also recommend that if possible, you modify your tables and columns to have really meaningful names. Aside from helping someone else who comes along and needs to support this system or read some data from it, you may find it helps you think about the meaning of the data as you're working on it. And again, it'll make things simpler if you need to come back and ask for help here. Even if it's too late for you to change it in the database, it might be worth making a diagram which has both the database-level name, and a descriptive term or phrase for each; data modelling is a lot easier when the meaning of what you're modelling is apparent.